# How do I SELECT the 10 highest scores only comparing the entries with the latest date for each user?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have 3 columns; name (VARCHAR), score (INT), submit_date (DATE).
Users with the same name can have multiple entries in the table.

I got close with:

```sql
SELECT name, Max(score) as maxScore, Max(submit_date) as submitDate 
FROM score_table 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY maxScore DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

The problem is this query only compares scores so even though a later submission date could have a lower score, it compares the higher score which is no longer interesting.

I need to somehow filter the table to only compare the latest submit_dates for each name and then order it by score.

Like

```sql
SELECT name, Max(score) as maxScore, Max(submit_date) as submitDate 
FROM score_table
WHERE submit_date = the_latest_submit_date_for_that_user??
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY Max(score)
LIMIT 10
```

EDIT: Adding example data and expected result

```
name  score  submit_date
------------------------
user1   4     2020-01-01
user1   1     2020-08-18
user2   2     2020-08-18
user3   3     2020-08-18
```

If I submit the query I highlighted first above with LIMIT 2 I would get user1 with score 4 and user3 with score 3. What I want to happen is get user3 with score 3 and user2 with score 2 since user1 has a later submission that has a score of 1 and I only want to compare the latest submit_date for each user.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Added clarification, let me know if it's not enough @GordonLinoff

Comment: Actually, your suggestion in the comment below was exactly what I was looking for, thank you! @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the most recent row per record, then use *filtering* not aggregation:

```
SELECT st.* 
FROM score_table st
WHERE st.submit_date = (SELECT MAX(st2.submit_date)
                        FROM score_table st2
                        WHERE st2.name = st.name
                       )
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated sub-query to retrieve the latest submit date for the user.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html

From the docs:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
  WHERE column1 = ANY (SELECT column1 FROM t2
                       WHERE t2.column2 = t1.column2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The query for your requirement can be like as below:

```
SELECT top 10 name, score as maxScore, submit_date 
from score_table s1 
inner join (
  select name,max(submit_date) as max_submit_date
  from score_table group by name) s2
on s1.name=s2.name and s1.submit_date =s2.max_submit_date
ORDER BY s1.Score DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in mysql :

```
select * 
from (select * from score_table order by name , submit_date desc, score desc) s
group by name
limit 10 ;
```